# Combining Multiple Excel Spreadsheet From SSRS In C# Console App

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, npoi

I am trying to combine a directory of Excel Workbooks that have 1 worksheet each which I generated from SSRS into one workbook without losing its formats and Cell Styles and merged cells.  I am trying use NPOI but I can't seem to fins anything that will keep my formatting (Each spreadsheet was generated from several sub reports into one report so the layout from SSRS is contains various merged regions).  Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?